# ¿Cómo ver/mostrar y editar código HTML?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un pequeño editor con características básicas, que me permite darle formato al texto y a la vez cada texto normal o con formato que se vaya escribiendo en el `div editable`, esa información con el mismo valor, pasa aún  `textarea` que permanece oculto, y a la vez se muestra la vista previa similar a **StackOverflow** que muestra una vista previa al escribir una pregunta.

Usted puede comprobarlo para familiarizarse:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#editControls a').click(function(e) {
  switch($(this).data('role')) {
             case 'p':
  document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
  break;
      default:
  document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
  break;
   }
    });

    let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
    htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
        $(".editor-preview").keyup();
    });

    $('.editor-preview').keyup(function(){
         var value = $(this).val();
         var contentAttr = $(this).attr( 'class' );
         $( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
    });
});
```

```css
.btn-group {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-group+.btn-group {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.btn-group a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-editor {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
    margin-left: -1px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-not-space{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    border-radius: inherit;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
    background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}
#editor {
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}
#preview {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 97%;
    border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-wrapper">
 <div id="editControls">
     <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
     </div>
       </div>
  <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
  <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
  <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
</div>
```

Funciona perfectamente, pero me hace falta una pequeña característica, que me permita insertar código de inserción por ejemplo un `iframe` de vídeo de youtube una publicación de twitter y a la vez poder agregar manualmente código `HTML`.

Para ello necesito un botón de etiqueta `<a>` que me permita ver el código generado y a la vez poder escribir código `HTML` y la opción de volver a la normalidad.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo implementar una función similar a la imagen, pero de una manera simple no muy compleja a mi editor, para poder escribir e insertar código `HTML`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un posible opción, aunque es un algo simple. La idea es tener un botón de código que cambie el contenido del `div` editable por la representación en modo texto de su código interno, y cuando se pulse de nuevo en el botón se vuelva a mostrar la representación del código como código. (no sé si me he explicado bien, pero es básicamente lo que quieres, lo prometo :P)

Esto se puede conseguir de manera simple con jQuery con los métodos [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) y [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/). Para mostrar el código interno en modo texto:

```
$(elemento).text( $(elemento).html() );
```

Y para volver a interpretar el código mostrado en modo texto se haría:

```
$(elemento).html( $(elemento).text() );
```

Como ves es bastante simple/básico. Lo único más a añadir sería una variable que controle en cuál de los modos estás (modo código `on` u `off`) para poder controlar qué se va a mostrar y dónde (no sólo en el editor pero también en la vista previa).

Aquí puedes verlo funcionando (con comentarios):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#editControls a').click(function(e) {
    switch ($(this).data('role')) {
      case 'p':
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
        break;
      // control específico para el botón de código
      case 'code':
        // activa/desactiva el modo código
        codeMode = !codeMode;
        if (codeMode) {
          // ON: muestra el código en modo texto
          htmlDiv.text(htmlDiv.html());
        } else {
          // OFF: reinterpreta el código
          htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text());
        }
        break;
      default:
        if (!codeMode) {
          document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
        } else {
          document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "&lt;" + $(this).data("tag") + "&gt;" + window.getSelection().toString() + "&lt;/" + $(this).data("tag") + "&gt;");
        }
        break;
    }
  });

  // control de modo código
  let codeMode = false;
  let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
  htmlDiv.on("input", function(e) {
    $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
    $(".editor-preview").keyup();
  });

  // dependiendo del modo muestra el código o ejecútalo
  $('.editor-preview').keyup(function() {
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr('class');
    if (!codeMode) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("div." + contentAttr).html(value);
    } else {
      $('div.' + contentAttr).html(htmlDiv.text());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-editor {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-not-space {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}

#editor {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#preview {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 97%;
  border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-wrapper">
  <div id="editControls">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-tag="b" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-tag="i" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-tag="u" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-tag="strike" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="code" data-ref="#"><code>&lt;/&gt;</code></a>
    </div>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Gracias, es lo que esperaba, una pregunta, que cambio debo realizar, para que los efectos de formato que realice al texto se muestre al mismo tiempo, si yo escribo un texto y luego decido seleccionarlo para aplicar la negrita, este añade en el editor editable pero no se muestra al mismo tiempo en la vista previa tengo que escrirbir para que el cambio se vea reflejado, que debo realizarle para que esto no suceda que los formatos aplicados se muestre al mismo tiempo, puedes sugerirme una solución a este pequeño problema por favor :)

Comment: @Stevin he añadido unos pequeños cambios al código: he puesto un `data-tag` a los botones de estilos, cuando se pulsa en uno de ellos (se entra en el default del switch) se comprueba si se está en modo código o no para poner el estilo directamente o el código HTML equivalente.

Comment: Disculpa amigo, lo que has actualizado es por lo de mi comentario? Sí es así, entonces no comprendiste lo quise decir, yo me refería a lo siguiente, por ejemplo: Ahora yo escribo un texto normal sin formato, es decir sin darle click a los botones, escribo lo siguiente: Juan se compro un carro, ahora yo decido ponerle en negrita el nombre de Juan, selecciono el nombre y presiono el botón **Bold** en el `div editable` se refleja que específicamente si se agrego la negrita al nombre,

Comment: pero si miras la vista previa que es la salida de lo que estás escribiendo no muestra al mismo tiempo el cambio, debo continuar escribiendo o dar un espacio en blanco para que se refleje el cambio de la negrita al nombre, en la vista previa, a ello me refería como puedo hacer que los cambios que se den al texto se reflejen al mismo tiempo en la vista previa, tiene usted mi amigo alguna sugerencia de cambio de código para este pequeño problema :) sí tiene una idea puede usted decirme por favor.

Comment: @Stevin cambia el tipo de evento de `keyup` a `input` y entonces se ejecutará cada vez que haya un cambio de valor. Edite la respuesta. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias amigo, solo era un pequeño cambio, eres lo máximo.