# ¿Cómo cambiar editor para pegar solo texto y organizar salida HTML?

Tags: html, jquery, formato

Estaba buscando un editor, algo sencillo y me encontré con la siguiente pregunta:

- [¿Cómo ver/mostrar y editar código HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197568/c%c3%b3mo-ver-mostrar-y-editar-c%c3%b3digo-html)

El mismo lo estoy usando adaptando a mi sistema de administración.

Pero **existen algunos problemas**, entre ellos lo siguiente:

- En cada tabulación que se proporciona, el código se genera con un `div` tipo contenedor y los párrafos en `br` de esta manera:

[image]

- Y, por otra parte, cada vez que se copia y pega algo en el editor, copia el formato desde donde lo haya copiado.

[image]

Entonces, ¿Cómo evitar el uso de `div` como contenedor y, evitar los párrafos en `br`? En lugar de ellos, que sean reemplazados, solo por `p` y de manera organizada, por ejemplo:

[image]

¿Cómo puedo corregir estos defectos del editor?

- Un *JSFiddle*: https://jsfiddle.net/p87t0aqx/

Código completo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#editControls a').click(function(e) {
    switch($(this).data('role')) {
      case 'p':
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
        break;
      //Specific control for the code button.
      case 'code':
        //enable / disable code mode
        codeMode = !codeMode;
        if(codeMode) {
          // ON: show the code in text mode
          htmlDiv.text(htmlDiv.html());
          //
          var editor = $("#editor")
          editor.addClass("black-bg-colr codeMode")
        } else {
          // OFF: reinterpret the code
          htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text());
          var editor = $("#editor")
          editor.removeClass("black-bg-colr codeMode")
        }
        break;
      default:
        document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
      break;
    }
  });

  //code mode control
  let codeMode = false;
  let htmlDiv = $("#editor");

  //input -> NOT keyup
  htmlDiv.on("input", function(e) {
  //htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
    $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
    //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());
    $(".editor-preview").keyup();
    //$(".editor-preview").html(htmlDiv.html());
  });
  //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

  $('.editor-preview').keyup(function(){
    //var value = $(this).val();
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr( 'class' );
    if (!codeMode) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
      $( '.' + contentAttr).html(value);
    } else {
      //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(htmlDiv.text());
      $( '.' + contentAttr).html(htmlDiv.text());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#editControls {
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: silver;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%; /*90*/
}
#editor {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;/*90*/
}
#editor:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px silver;
}
.codeMode {
    font-family:Courier New,Source Code Pro Light,Medium,Source Code Pro ExtraLight,Menlo,Consola,Monaco Linux,Consola Regular,Fira Code Regular,DejaVu Sans Mono;
    /*font-family: inherit;*/
    /*font-family: 'Courier New';*/
    border: 0px;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-variant: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-stretch: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    color: #fff;
}
.black-bg-colr {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
.btn-group {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-group+.btn-group {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.btn-group a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-editor {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
    margin-left: -1px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-not-space{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    border-radius: inherit;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
    background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}
#preview {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 97%;
    border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="editor-wrapper">
  <div id="editControls">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="code" data-ref="#"><code>&lt;/&gt;</code></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
  <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
  <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Advertencia:[**El uso de execCommand está desaconsejado**](https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html)

Comment: Está funcionalidad dentro de los navegadores es muy limitada y no mejorará con el tiempo (de hecho, es posible que desaparezca). Aconsejaría usar alguna librería para editar textos enriquecidos.

Comment: Te fijate en TinyMCE? https://www.tiny.cloud/

Comment: @PabloLozano En el caso de esta pregunta, aunque no lo usan para copiar texto al portapapeles, tengo entendido que no hay otra manera de copiar al portapapeles que obligatoriamente usar execCommand. De manera que no es totalmente desaconsejable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya se menciono, se recomendó que está funcionalidad dentro de los navegadores es muy limitada y no mejorará con el tiempo (de hecho, es posible que desaparezca), sin embargo pueda que sea como se decía anteriormente de Java, pero aquí la solución:

- Formatee el código `HTML` en `Code Toggle` antes de mostrarlo.
- Detecta la tecla `Enter` y aplica el `<p>` formato; de lo contrario, aplica el mismo formato.
- En `Clipboard Paste`, intercepte el comportamiento predeterminado de pegado del portapapeles y luego inserte texto plano en la posición actual del cursor del editor.

```js
$(function () {
    var aceEditor = ace.edit("ace-editor");
    aceEditor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
    aceEditor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");

    $('#editControls a').click(function (e) {
        switch ($(this).data('role')) {
            case 'p':
                document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
                break;
            //Specific control for the code button.
            case 'code':
                //enable / disable code mode
                codeMode = !codeMode;
                if (codeMode) {
                    // ON: show the code in text mode
                    var editor = $("#editor");
                    var $aceEditor = $("#ace-editor");

                    var formattedHtml = html_beautify(htmlDiv.html());

                    aceEditor.setValue(formattedHtml, -1);

                    editor.css("display", "none");
                    $aceEditor.css("display", "block");

                } else {
                    // OFF: reinterpret the code
                    htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
                    var editor = $("#editor");
                    var $aceEditor = $("#ace-editor");

                    editor.css("display", "block");
                    $aceEditor.css("display", "none");

                    htmlDiv.html(aceEditor.getValue().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
                }
                break;
            default:
                document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
                break;
        }
    });

    //code mode control
    let codeMode = false;
    let htmlDiv = $("#editor");

    htmlDiv.on("paste", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    });

    //input -> NOT keyup
    htmlDiv.on("input", function (e) {
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
        //htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
        //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());
        $(".editor-preview").keyup();
        //$(".editor-preview").html(htmlDiv.html());
    });
    //$("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

    aceEditor.getSession().on('change', function () {
        $('.editor-preview').html(aceEditor.getValue().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
    });

    $('.editor-preview').keyup(function () {
        //var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr('class');
        if (!codeMode) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
            $('.' + contentAttr).html(value);
        } else {
            //$( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(htmlDiv.text());
            $('.' + contentAttr).html(htmlDiv.text());
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#editControls {
  overflow: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: silver;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px silver;
}

.codeMode {
  font-family: Courier New, Source Code Pro Light, Medium, Source Code Pro ExtraLight, Menlo, Consola, Monaco Linux, Consola Regular, Fira Code Regular, DejaVu Sans Mono;
  /*font-family: inherit;*/
  /*font-family: 'Courier New';*/
  border: 0px;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: #fff;
}

.black-bg-colr {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-editor {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-not-space {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}

#preview {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 97%;
  border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  clear: both;
}

#ace-editor {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>WYSIWYG</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/ace.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/ext-beautify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.10.3/beautify-html.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="editor-wrapper">
    <div id="editControls">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="code" data-ref="#"><code>&lt;/&gt;</code></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
    <div id="ace-editor"></div>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Con el aporte de:

[Javascript: ¿Cómo corregir la sangría en una cadena HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360414/javascript-how-to-correct-indentation-in-html-string)

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu respuesta corrigiendo los errores? Cada vez que escribo una letra en el textarea aparece un error, podrías detectarlos con un try catch.

Answer (score 4):

Quizás te pueda interesar [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/).

Prueba insertando este código en tu proyecto. *No funciona aquí si lo agrego como snippet.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CKEditor</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
  <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Es un editor de texto enriquecido `HTML` altamente conocido y de uso gratuito (o de pago si deseas mejores características).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al activar el botón **Fuente HTML** tendrás una vista limpia del código...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si copias información de otros sitios se verá así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y su respectivo código se verá así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La mejor opción es usar una librería externa como esta, la opción mencionada por el OP por ahora es experimental y es probable que no sea desarrollada más de lo que está.

Comment: @Lou Este editor ha sido usado intensivamente en Drupal 6 y 7 (No se en otras versiones porque no las uso) y es excelente para el propósito que manifiestas